# One liner with awk selecting a range between negative to positive values?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to run an awk command to select few columns of a .txt file with a particular range of values for a specific column. I am using column 10 which has distance scores both positive and negative and I want to select few column from that file for the interval -1000 to 1000 for the column 10. I used the below command but it does not run

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{if($10 >= -1000 && $10 <= 1000)print $2,$3,$4,$5,$8,$10$16} file.txt > promoter.txt
```

But it fails.

My file looks like below

```
PeakID (cmd=S_13_O1_122_K27me3_macs2_out_broad_peaks.c.bed.uniq hg19)   Chr Start   End Strand  Peak Score  Focus Ratio/Region Size Annotation  Detailed Annotation Distance to TSS Nearest PromoterID  Entrez ID   Nearest Unigene Nearest Refseq  Nearest Ensembl Gene Name   Gene Alias  Gene Description    Gene Type
MACS_peak_5016  chr13   73353448    73357948    +   7673    NA  promoter-TSS (NM_006346)    promoter-TSS (NM_006346)    -1532   NM_006346   10464   Hs.441926   XM_005266229    ENSG00000083535 PIBF1   C13orf24|CEP90|PIBF|RP11-505F3.1    progesterone immunomodulatory binding factor 1  protein-coding
MACS_peak_9676  chr2    10829010    10830914    +   7640    NA  exon (NM_024894, exon 1 of 21)  exon (NM_024894, exon 1 of 21)  151 NM_024894   79954   Hs.222494   NM_001261392    ENSG00000115761 NOL10   PQBP5   nucleolar protein 10    protein-coding
MACS_peak_3106  chr11   45938540    45940401    +   6981    NA  5' UTR (NM_004813, exon 1 of 11)    5' UTR (NM_004813, exon 1 of 11)    203 NM_057174   9409    Hs.100915   NM_004813   ENSG00000121680 PEX16   PBD8A|PBD8B peroxisomal biogenesis factor 16    protein-coding
MACS_peak_4282  chr12   57984413    57986062    +   6898    NA  exon (NM_024779, exon 1 of 10)  exon (NM_024779, exon 1 of 10)  296 NM_001146258    79837   Hs.745011   XM_005269152    ENSG00000166908 PIP4K2C PIP5K2C phosphatidylinositol-5-phosphate 4-kinase, type II, gamma   protein-coding
MACS_peak_4962  chr13   48667810    48669433    +   6886    NA  intron (NM_001270629, intron 1 of 6)    L2c|LINE|L2 655 NM_014166   29079   Hs.741275   NM_001270629    ENSG00000136146 MED4    ARC36|DRIP36|HSPC126|TRAP36|VDRIP   mediator complex subunit 4  protein-coding
MACS_peak_6695  chr16   28856397    28858825    +   6773    NA  5' UTR (NM_003321, exon 1 of 10)    5' UTR (NM_003321, exon 1 of 10)    118 NM_003321   7284    Hs.12084    NM_003321   ENSG00000178952 TUFM    COXPD4|EF-TuMT|EFTU|P43 Tu translation elongation factor, mitochondrial protein-coding
MACS_peak_1985  chr10   14879403    14881608    +   6694    NA  promoter-TSS (NM_001029954) promoter-TSS (NM_001029954) 347 NR_103464   51182   Hs.736996   NM_001037538    ENSG00000187522 HSPA14  HSP70-4|HSP70L1 heat shock 70kDa protein 14 protein-coding
MACS_peak_7035  chr16   84219653    84220691    +   6592    NA  intron (NM_001243156, intron 1 of 14)   AluSz6|SINE|Alu 1504    NM_139353   9013    Hs.153022   XM_005256226    ENSG00000103168 TAF1C   MGC:39976|SL1|TAFI110|TAFI95    TATA box binding protein (TBP)-associated factor, RNA polymerase I, C, 110kDa   protein-coding
MACS_peak_87    chr1    6613157 6614770 +   6592    NA  intron (NM_024654, intron 1 of 11)  intron (NM_024654, intron 1 of 11)  694 NM_024654   79707   Hs.59425    XM_005263493    ENSG00000162408 NOL9    Grc3|NET6   nucleolar protein 9 protein-coding
MACS_peak_6893  chr16   67192557    67195235    +   6527    NA  promoter-TSS (NM_003789)    promoter-TSS (NM_003789)    5   NM_018378   55336   Hs.710714   NM_018378   ENSG00000135722 FBXL8   FBL8    F-box and leucine-rich repeat protein 8 protein-coding
MACS_peak_11932 chr22   22335769    22337385    +   6527    NA  intron (NM_001282112, intron 1 of 17)   intron (NM_001282112, intron 1 of 17)   663 NM_001282112    8940    Hs.436401   XM_005261810    ENSG00000100038 TOP3B   TOP3B1  topoisomerase (DNA) III beta    protein-coding
```

Now the output on the above should exclude two rows which are outside of range -1000 to 1000. But this command does not seems to work. Where am I getting wrong.

Comment: Do you mean `$11` instead of `$10`?

Comment: We need to know more about the structure of the data - it's not clear what the exact format is. By default, awk splits each record into fields on any kind of space characters so the number of fields on the second line is different to the third because of parts like `promoter-TSS (NM_006346)` vs. `exon (NM_024894, exon 1 of 21)`. Perhaps a regex-based approach would be more suitable. Either way you should show us your desired output.

Comment: It seems to be a problem of the header and when I select the few fields from the parent file and then run the awk , it works, so it seems to be a problem of the parent file format

Comment: debugging should be trivial just `print $10` to check whether you're able to extract the right values for each row (you're not!)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "\t" } $10 >= -1000 && $10 <= 1000 {print $2,$3,$4,$5,$8,$10$16} file.txt > promoter.txt
```

you define only OFS (output separator but keep input separator (FS) generic so with space character)